# How to figure out what causes hardware issues?

Tags: hardware, error-handling

So for a week now I'm experiencing issues that distort the appearance on many programs such as Firefox while dayly use. Ultimately this causes most programs to crash. I pinpointed this to be a hardware issue, since reinstalling or using different operation systems doesn't help. Things I tried so far:

- Reinstall (Ubuntu Gnome 14.04) and different operation systems
- Different graphic card
- Memtest86 (overnight, no errors)
- new hard disk
- overheating test (cpuburn)

None of these changed or help with the issues. How can I get to the bottom of this and retrieve relevant error logs?

Comment: Can you give us the details of how you pinpointed your issues to be hardware?  Also you might consider performing and install and working on one program at a time to try to resolve the issue with the specific program.

Comment: I figure that reinstalling and using entirely different Operation System would solve any Software issues. Also, I changed only one parameter each time.

Comment: I can't identify with the other operating systems, but as for Ubuntu, you'll have to actually install it and specify the exact error or problem that you're having.  You'll find someone who can help.  People often experience problem with every OS.  The resolution comes from posting a description of the problem (the error message), as well as their specific hardware environment, and we provide steps for working with the specific issue.  You said your problems starts with Firefox.  It might have something to do with a site that you visit that exploits your system.  This can happen with any OS.

Comment: My problem is that my computer is not usable anymore. Any program on any system, including Firefox will produce graphic errors and ultimately crash without warning. I didn't have any problems for the better part of a year and now regardless of the software I'm using, I see these errors. It even happens at the startup screen of a live CD. I will provide data on my Hardware Environment.

Answer (score 0):

A good program for hardware diagnostic is Ultimate Boot.  You can download a bootable ISO at:

http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/
http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html

While there are lots of links on the download page, the actual ISO download links are located under the `mirror sites` section.